# Unable to use expressions in Thymeleaf / Spring4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Having used Tiles I fancied a go at using Thymeleaf templating instead, however, I seem unable to use any expressions in the HTML pages at all.

I've tried using a quick start Spring MVC using the project starter and it all works fine when rendering to jsp, but not using HTML with Thymeleaf - the HTML pages are shown, so it's obviously working to a degree, but all expressions show as simple text and not evaluated.

Here's the Thymeleaf parts of servlet-context.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="templateResolver"
class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <beans:property name="additionalDialects">
        <beans:set>
        <beans:bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect" />
        </beans:set>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</beans:bean>
```

The controller is just the generated one from the quick-start MVC template:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {        
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
    return "home";
    }
}
```

The HTML is just copied over from the jsp with extra Thymleaf expressions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>  (HTML)The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </p>
#{serverTime}

<h1>th:text:="#{serverTime}"</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas of what I'm missing here?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to your html, Thymeleaf uses standard dialect that defines html attributes starting with `th:`

Your html body should look like:

```
<body>
<p>The time on the server is <span th:text="${serverTime}">time</span>.</p>

<h1 th:text="${serverTime}">Time again!</h1>

</body>
```

I recommend you reading the tutorial "[Using Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html)"

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but I've already tried that - apologies but the html example I posted was just one of many attempts made and a bit scrappy.  I've read through the tutorial you suggested (and a few others), and even exactly copying the examples results in the same.

EDIT:  Sorry, I mean if included within an html tag like you suggest then they are just completely omitted.

Comment: I removed the additional LayoutDialect and now it all seems to work just fine.

Comment: Great news! i missed that line of the additional dialect. Some aditional info: as you mention you previously used Tiles, you could use the Thymeleaf Tiles Integration (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html) it works really fine.

Comment: I'll certainly look into the Tiles integration - I'll leave the LayoutDialect as a battle for another day!  Thanks again for your help.